# Perl hash dereferencing

Tags: perl

I am working through Intermediate Perl by brian d foy (2nd ed). I'm on the section dealing with references to hashes. I have run one of the scripts in Strawberry Perl and I'm not sure I'm getting the intended results. the script is:

```
 my %gilligan_info = (
  name     => 'Gilligan',
  hat      => 'White',
  shirt    => 'Red',
  position => 'First Mate',
);
my %skipper_info = (
  name     => 'Skipper',
  hat      => 'Black',
  shirt    => 'Blue',
  position => 'Captain',
);
my @crew = (\%gilligan_info, \%skipper_info);

my $format = "%−15s %−7s %−7s %−15s\n";
printf $format, qw(Name Shirt Hat Position);
for my $crewmember (@crew) {
  printf $format, @$crewmember{qw(name shirt hat position)};
}
```

The output I am seeing is

[image]

I thought this example was going to show actual values, but I am just seeing memory addresses (I think)..

Can somebody please advise
thanks
John

Comment: Thanks. I was using notepad++ with utf-8.  I copied the script from a kindle ebook and it must have come in with some strange encoding. Typed it out manually and it works.

Comment: Looks like  `$format` has `U+2212 − MINUS SIGN` instead of `U+002D - HYPHEN-MINUS`. The joys of Unicode :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using word as your editor? I say this because it looks like your format is using n-dash or m-dash instead of - and word will do this automatically. Get hold of notpad++ and use that as your editor.

Answer (score 0):

I used NotePad++ to paste and save. The code worked as-is for me with no changes.

If you take the current code and paste it into MS Word, it will look normal. Save it and open in Notepad++. You'll see that

```
my $format = "%-15s %-7s %-7s %-15s\n";
```

is changed to

```
my $format = "%?15s %?7s %?7s %?15s\n";
```